# What are domestic animals that are kosher to raise and quiet?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals

I want to get an animal to raise and want to be sure to comply with *halacha*. So I would like to know which animals are kosher to raise in a Jewish home?

I am particularly interested in animals which are quiet and won't disturb others in my home.

Comment: Kids! Raise lots of kids! (Not particularly quiet though).

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30119/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95450/759

Comment: Not sure why you want kosher specifically, but quite and kosher sounds like you want kosher species of fish

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I think Avi means "kosher to have as pets", not "kosher as food animals".

Comment: @MonicaCellio you may be right, but the other possibility is that some people have a kabalah thingy not to have even pictures of non-kosher animals around, so it may be that.

Comment: Cats are quiet. They're pretty easy to take care of too, as long as you're faithful in changing the litter box.

Comment: monica cellio i mean kosher as food

Comment: no fish because i already have fish in my house